# Would you show how many different orders in this case is possible?

Tags: combinatorics

You want to arrange your disks so that the cd's of the same artist come in a row and you have 20 cd's from five different artists four from each. How many different orders in this case is possible?

My solution

> Firstly the cd's of each artist can be arranged $4 \cdot 4!=96$ different ways. 
>   In addition each artist can be arranged $5!=120$ different ways. Thus by the principle of product in combinatorics the total number of different orders is $96 \cdot 120 = 11520$. I would like to ask if this is right result and if you wish to show your own result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $4$ cd's can be arranged in $4!$ different ways and $5$ artists can be arranged in $5!$ different ways  I think that solution is given by :

$5! \cdot (4! \cdot 4! \cdot 4! \cdot 4! \cdot 4! ) =  5! \cdot (4!)^5 $ different ways .

Comment: In my calculations I got $5! \cdot 5 \cdot 4! = 12600$. Are you sure that it is 14400? No I got the same result. It is $120 \cdot 120= 14400$

Comment: @alvoutila,$120 \cdot 5 \cdot 24$

Comment: @AndréNicolas,Of course...thanks..